# Calculator GUI ActionPerformed method, and wrapping around another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, wrapper

I am trying to wrap a Calculator GUI over a class that I built to calculate values in a different way (not the normal way, in reverse Polish notation).

I just wanted to know two things:

1) How do I write my actionPerformed method so that when you click on a button or operation, it shows up in the display

2) How do I go about using the GUI with the calculation method (like how to make it so that when you press all the numbers or operators on the GUI, it registers in my calculation class). Basically how to wrap the GUI over it?

**Edit, I edited my code, but when it compiles it gives me a null pointer exception, how come?

My GUI Class so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JPanel buttonPanel, topPanel, operationPanel;
JTextField display;

doMath math = new doMath();

JButton Num1;
JButton Num2;
JButton Num3;
JButton Num4;
JButton Num5;
JButton Num6;
JButton Num7;
JButton Num8;
JButton Num9;
JButton Num0;

JButton Add;
JButton Sub;
JButton Mult;
JButton Div;
JButton Eq;
JButton Clr;
public GUI()
{
    super("Calculator");
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,1));

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();        
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
    buttonPanel.add(Num1 = new JButton("1"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num2 = new JButton("2"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num3 = new JButton("3"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num4 = new JButton("4"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num5 = new JButton("5"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num6 = new JButton("6"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num7 = new JButton("7"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num8 = new JButton("8"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num9 = new JButton("9"));
    buttonPanel.add(Num0 = new JButton("0"));        
    buttonPanel.add(Clr = new JButton("C"));
    buttonPanel.add(Eq = new JButton("="));
    buttonPanel.add(Add = new JButton("+"));
    buttonPanel.add(Sub = new JButton("-"));
    buttonPanel.add(Mult = new JButton("*"));
    buttonPanel.add(Div = new JButton("/"));


    Num1.addActionListener(this);
    Num2.addActionListener(this);
    Num3.addActionListener(this);
    Num4.addActionListener(this);
    Num5.addActionListener(this);
    Num6.addActionListener(this);
    Num7.addActionListener(this);
    Num8.addActionListener(this);
    Num9.addActionListener(this);
    Num0.addActionListener(this);
    Clr.addActionListener(this);
    Eq.addActionListener(this);
    Add.addActionListener(this);
    Sub.addActionListener(this);
    Mult.addActionListener(this);
    Div.addActionListener(this);

    topPanel = new JPanel();         
    topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    topPanel.add(new JTextField(20));
   //jtfResult.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
   // jtfResult.setEditable(false);  

    add(mainPanel);

    mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
     if(e.getSource() == Num1)
    {
        s += "1";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num2)
    {
        s += "2";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num3)
    {
        s += "3";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num4)
    {
        s += "4";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num5)
    {
        s += "5";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num6)
    {
        s += "6";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num7)
    {
        s += "7";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num8)
    {
        s += "8";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num9)
    {
        s += "9";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Num0)
    {
        s += "0";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Add)
    {
        s += "+";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Sub)
    {
        s += "-";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Mult)
    {
        s += "*";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Div)
    {
        s += "/";
        display.setText(s);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == Eq)
    {
        String result = "" + math.doMath1(s);
        display.setText(result);
    }

}
}
```

My calculation class (works as intended to, just need to know how to wrap my GUI over it):

```
public class doMath
{
Stack stack = new Stack();

String next = "";

public doMath()
{

}

public int doMath1(String expr)
{
    while( expr.length()  >0) //for(int i = 0; i < expr.length(); i++)
{              
    if(expr.length() == 0)
        return 0;
    if(expr.indexOf(" ")>0)
    {
        next = expr.substring(0,expr.indexOf(" "));

        if(next.equals("+"))
            stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
        else if(next.equals("-"))
        {
            int x = stack.pop();
            stack.push(stack.pop()- x);
        }
        else if(next.equals("*"))
            stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop());
        else if(next.equals("/"))
        {
            int x = stack.pop();
            stack.push(stack.pop()/ stack.pop());
        }
        else 
        stack.push(new Integer(Integer.parseInt(next)));         
         expr = expr.substring(expr.indexOf(" ")+1);
    }        
}

    return stack.pop();
}    
}
```

**Errors:**

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:126)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.
    mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at         java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy
    (EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy
    (EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Comment: I would look here for a good tutorial on this kind of thing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html It's a tutorial on how to write actionListeners

Comment: You seem to have a ton of JButtons. If this was me and I wanted to have the same action listener for them I would use arrays and for loops instead of repetitively typing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, you seem to have a workable model.

Basically you need to attach a `ActionListener` to each button.  In your case, I'd use a single instance of the same listener...

```
ActionListener calculatorActionHandler = new CalculatorActionHandler();
Num1.addActionListener(calculatorActionHandler);
```

In this handler I would take the text of the button and concatenate them together

```
public class CalculatorActionHandler implements ActionListener {
    private StringBuilder expression = new StringBuilder(32);
    private Gui gui;

    public CalculatorActionHandler(Gui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String text = source.getText();
        if (text.equals("=")) {
            doMath math = new doMath();
            int result = math.doMath1(expression.toString());
            expession = new StringBuilder(32);
            // Update the UI
        } else {
            expession.append(text);
            // Update this value to the screen, maybe using a JLabel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: trying to update the UI, I though it would be easier to do this
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class CalcActionHandler implements ActionListener 
{
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
    String text = source.getText();
    String s= "";
    if (text.equals("=")) {
    doMath math = new doMath();
    int result = math.doMath1(s);
    String answer = ""+result;
    gui.display.setText(answer);
    } else {
    s += text;
    gui.display.setText(s);
           
  }
  }
}

Comment: I didn't want to use a string builder, so I just added each value to the string so that I could put it on my text field, but it is giving me an insets error in my gui when I try to compile, could you help me out with this?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new `GUI` inside the action listener, this makes it local reference to the action listener and makes no difference to what you have on the screen.  Instead, I might pass a reference to the `GUI` to the action listener when it's created.  Also, you create a blank `String` each time the action event is fired, which means you are no longer maintaining the expression, only the last key pressed

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `StringBuilder`? It is more efficient then string concatenation

Comment: Mainly cause I have never used it before

Comment: String concatenation is an expensive operation in Java, for each concatenation, Java needs to create n + 1 String objects (so that `s += text` ends up creating three String objects).  Short lived objects such as these can have an adverse effect on the garbage collector over time. While typically we're talk about having to do 100's of concatenations in a short period, it's good practice to avoid it if you can.

Comment: Thanks, I used this, but put it in my action performed instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a good start by implementing ActionListener.

You need to add

```
addActionListener(this)
```

to each of your `JButton`s.

Then for each button you need an if statement, or possibly a switch would be better in this case, but it should look like this:

```
String text = "";

....

if(e.getSource() == Num1)
{
    text += "1"
    display.setText(text);
}

/*continue this pattern for the other
  buttons, adding the character to the 
  text string */
```

For your equals button, call the `doMath` method on the expression entered and write the result to the display.

There might be errors in the above code, you should probably consult the link I posted in an above comment.

Comment: In my constructor I put 
Num1.addActionListner(this); 
Num2.addActionListener(this); 
etc...

and in my actionperformed I put the if statement you had for each button. The code compiles, but when I click on a button I get a null pointer exception... I'll edit the code I have, and put the error I get

Comment: Do you ever declare the String s